# What is difference between <div md-dialog-actions> & <mat-dialog-actions>?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I found two ways of approaches to create a section where are actions buttons of form, visually in page they are look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Official docs https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content

`<mat-dialog-actions>`: Container for action buttons at the bottom of the dialog. Button alignment can be controlled via the align attribute which can be set to end and center.

I've seen `<div-md-dialog-actions>` too in other questions and answers, it seems to be an outdated way to do it. I've always used `<mat-dialog-actions>`.